# How can I verify linked libraries?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, shared-libraries

I am having lots of trouble getting a specific set of drivers working, called [libnifalcon](http://qdot.github.io/libnifalcon/).

I am pretty sure that the installation was successful, but when I try to compile the example programs I get the errors:

```
mars@marslab:~/Documents/libnifalcon-1.0/examples/findfalcons$ g++ findfalcons.cpp 
/tmp/cc8TtfGn.o: In function `runFalconTest()':
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::FalconDevice()'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::getDeviceCount(unsigned int&)'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::open(unsigned int)'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::isFirmwareLoaded()'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconFirmware::loadFirmware(bool, unsigned int const&, unsigned char*)'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::isFirmwareLoaded()'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x3dd): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::runIOLoop(unsigned int)'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x504): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::runIOLoop(unsigned int)'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x512): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::close()'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x52b): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::~FalconDevice()'
findfalcons.cpp:(.text+0x53f): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconDevice::~FalconDevice()'
/tmp/cc8TtfGn.o: In function `void libnifalcon::FalconDevice::setFalconFirmware<libnifalcon::FalconFirmwareNovintSDK>()':
findfalcons.cpp:(.text._ZN11libnifalcon12FalconDevice17setFalconFirmwareINS_23FalconFirmwareNovintSDKEEEvv[void libnifalcon::FalconDevice::setFalconFirmware<libnifalcon::FalconFirmwareNovintSDK>()]+0x1d): undefined reference to `libnifalcon::FalconFirmwareNovintSDK::FalconFirmwareNovintSDK()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I verify the libraries are linked correctly? What can I do if they aren't?

Comment: You are calling functions that are not defined in such scope. Did you written the code?

Comment: no, I'm trying to run example programs.

I've verified that the namespace exists (in a separate file) and the functions are declared within it

Comment: Now I see, *out of the box*. Where did you get the source?

Comment: http://qdot.github.io/libnifalcon/

Comment: @koodawg you should re-write your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking with anything, i.e.

```
g++ file.cpp
```

does not link to any libraries other than the standard library. You need to link with other modules or libraries, probably libnifalcon

```
g++ findfalcons.cpp -lnifalcon
```

or... you probably will need to do something like

```
g++ -L/path/to/libnifalcon findfalcons.cpp -lnifalcon
```

where -I tells where to look for libraries.

Comment: `-I` is for header files, you want `-L` to set a search path for libraries, or just set the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for dynamic libraries).

Comment: it's still not working but I think we're getting closer. I thought it was a typo when you wrote -lnifalcon instead of -libnifalcon, but -lnifalcon will compile and give me the same erros I always get, but -libnifalcon gives me the "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libnifalcon" error. How did you know to use -lnifalcon?

Comment: That's the standard way to specify libraries, you drop the "lib" - see 'man ld'. Sounds like you don't have the correct path to libnifalcon specified with -L option (or LD_LIBRARY_PATH as mentioned by Paul Griffiths).

Comment: I've found the proper path, the -lnifalcon doesn't return an error (like it did when I had the wrong path) but I still get the undefined references. Should I look in libnifalcon.a to see if they are there?

Comment: Correct! Also, make sure your executable has the libraries you intend for it to i.e. 'ldd program' shows you all the libs linked to program. (otool on osx). Then, I'd do something like 'nm prog | grep symbol' to check the binary for the undefined you're looking for.